# How does one share a single name among a group of Java Objects?

Tags: java

The title may or may not make sense, but my question is how can I "override" an object to a different type?

I doubt this is even possible, but I'm not quite sure how to tackle this problem any other way.

I am creating a small platforming game in Java, and all the levels are assigned to class objects. Such as Level 1 would be in the class Level1, and instantiated by:

```
Level1 platforms = new Level1();
```

The way I draw objects (and similarly check for collision) is described in this loop:

```
Level1 platforms = new Level1();
//grabs number of platforms for level 1
int platformNum = platforms.getNumberOfPlatforms();
//creates platforms for level 1
for(int i=0;i<=platformNum;i++){
    int x1=platforms.getPlatformCoords(i,1);
    int y1=platforms.getPlatformCoords(i,2);
    int x2=platforms.getPlatformCoords(i,3);
    int y2=platforms.getPlatformCoords(i,4);
    x2-=x1;
    y2-=y1;
    g.fillRect(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

How can I change the statement `Level1 platforms = new Level1();` so that `platforms` can be of a certain type depending on a variable `level`, such that when `level == 1`, platforms will be of `Level1`, and so forth?

Comment: This sound like a case for the factory pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a FactoryMethod:

```
Level platform = LevelFactory.getLevel(level);
```

Inside LevelFactory:

```
public Level getLevel(int level){
   if(level==1)return new Level1();
   if(level==2)return new Level2();
 //...
}
```

In order for this to work, each level has to extend or implement a Level class or interface.

Answer (score 3):

There's a bit of a code smell to this, but what I think you want is an interface for a basic `Level`.  To add to that, you're going to want to use a factory to create the levels for you on the fly.

```
public class LevelFactory {

    public Level getLevel(int level) {
        switch(level) {
            case 1:
            return new Level1();
            case 2:
            return new Level2();
            default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Level not valid");
        }
    }
}

public interface Level {
    int getNumberOfPlatforms();
    int getPlatformCoords(int x, int y);
}
```

In that instance, so long as all of your levels implement `Level`...

```
public class Level1 implements Level { }

public class Level2 implements Level { }
```

...you would just need to get the level you care about at the time to use.

```
Level platforms = LevelFactory.getLevel(1);
```